# Get the old values in my editForm - Symfony

Tags: forms, symfony

I'd like to know if theres a way to get the old values of the entity I'm updating in my edit form, in Symfony

I have a condition in my EntityType.php, in my eventListener, where I'd like to check if enable === true or false. I dont want to get the field value, but the value of the enable field my entity has before editing it

I tried to get it from the $options['data'] but it only gives me the form values (i'm a beginner)